# Range.Address Truncated when Used in Formula (String Too Long)

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I have code that loops through the 5th column of a user-selected range, and if the current cell in the 5th column matches a criteria, adds the next 10 cells in the same row to a range. At the end of everything, it sums the final range in cell A1 if it is empty.

```
Sub SumItems()
   Dim selectedRange As Range
   Set selectedRange = Selection

   Dim sumRange As Range
   Dim i As Long
   For i = 1 To selectedRange.Rows.Count
      If selectedRange(i, 5) = "Yes" Then
         If sumRange Is Nothing Then
            Set sumRange = Range(selectedRange(i, 5).Offset(0, 1), selectedRange(i, 5).Offset(0, 10))
         Else
            Set sumRange = Union(sumRange, Range(selectedRange(i, 5).Offset(0, 1), selectedRange(i, 5).Offset(0, 10)))
         End If
      End If
   Next i

   If Not sumRange Is Nothing Then
      If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
         Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + sumRange.Address(False, False) + ")"
      Else
         MsgBox "Cannot paste in cell A1, it is not empty."
         Exit Sub
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox "No matching rows were found."
      Exit Sub
   End If
End Sub
```

The sheets I am running this on are long. So sumRange will usually be a union of a lot of different areas in the sheet. I've noticed that once sumRange.Areas.Count exceeds 18, I have problems with the Range("A1").Formula statement. The sumRange.Address(False, False) string gets cut off after the 18th area. I believe this is because the .Address string length is too long and it just coincides with 18 areas with this sheet.

I developed a temporary solution but it limits the number of areas the subroutine can handle and is clunky and verbose. I set up temporary range variables to split sumRange into if it has more than 18 areas and the IF statement now reads something like:

```
If Not sumRange Is Nothing Then
   If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) Then
      If sumRange.Areas.Count > 18 Then
         Dim k As Long
         Dim tmpSumRange1 As Range
         Dim tmpSumRange2 As Range
         Dim tmpSumRange3 As Range
         ' And so on...
         For k = 1 To sumRange.Areas.Count
            If k <= 18 Then
               If tmpSumRange1 Is Nothing Then
                  Set tmpSumRange1 = sumRange.Areas(k)
               Else
                  Set tmpSumRange1 = Union(tmpSumRange1, sumRange.Areas(k))
               End If
            ElseIf k > 18 And k <= 36 Then
               If tmpSumRange2 Is Nothing Then
                  Set tmpSumRange2 = sumRange.Areas(k)
               Else
                  Set tmpSumRange2 = Union(tmpSumRange2, sumRange.Areas(k))
               End If
            ElseIf k > 36 And k <= 54 Then
               If tmpSumRange3 Is Nothing Then
                  Set tmpSumRange3 = sumRange.Areas(k)
               Else
                  Set tmpSumRange3 = Union(tmpSumRange3, sumRange.Areas(k))
               End If

            ElseIf
               ' And so on until I get to k = 180...
            End If
         Next k

         If Not tmpSumRange1 Is Nothing And tmpSumRange2 Is Nothing And tmpSumRange3 Is Nothing Then
            Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + tmpSumRange1.Address(False, False) + ")"
         ElseIf Not tmpSumRange1 Is Nothing And Not tmpSumRange2 Is Nothing And tmpSumRange3 Is Nothing Then
            Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + tmpSumRange1.Address(False, False) + "," + tmpSumRange2.Address(False, False) + ")"
         ElseIf Not tmpSumRange1 Is Nothing And tmpSumRange2 Is Nothing And Not tmpSumRange3 Is Nothing Then
            Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + tmpSumRange1.Address(False, False) + "," + tmpSumRange2.Address(False, False) + "," + tmpSumRange3.Address(False, False) + ")"
         ElseIf
            ' And so on all the way up to tmpSumRange10...
         End If
      Else
         Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" + sumRange.Address(False, False) + ")"
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox "Cannot paste in cell A1, it is not empty."
      Exit Sub
   End If
Else
   MsgBox "No matching rows were found."
   Exit Sub
End If
```

I know there has to be a better solution than this. I haven't found anything in my searching. Nor have I found anyone that has experienced the same problem. I need the A1 cell to have the SUM formula with the ranges in it otherwise I would just sum the values in the subroutine and insert the value instead of the formula.

Comment: Can you give example of what these addresses look like? Because I think the limit is not imposed by number of areas, but rather by the string length of the addresses. If so, I'm pretty sure there are other related solutions on here for dealing with "very long" formula evaluations.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yeah that's what it is. I think it just coincides with 18 areas on this sheet, but it would be more/less if run on other sheets with different data. It's definitely a string length issue, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: well, I still may have spoken too soon. 255 is the longest *string* you can pass to a cell value or formula, but actual formulas can be longer than that. See [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/833365-formula-too-long-vba-handle-syntax-error-post4064274.html#post4064274).

Comment: Yeah, the formula can be longer than that. With the temporary variables I use, all of the areas get into the formula and it sums everything correctly. It's just is there any way to do it without that mess? Or have I just hit a hard limit with VBA and this is the reality?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. But instead of hard-coding three temporary variables, do it as a collection or array representing the ranges and you should always be checking for that limit of 255 characters, not the size of the areas, that way it's more flexible and less prone to errors if the structure of the sheet/workbook changes.

Comment: @DavidZemens Hey, sorry to bother again. I am putting the ArrayList solution through a test and I am running into an error when the Join statement gets past a certain length. I have `Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Join(myRanges.ToArray(), ",") & ")"` and I run a check on the length of the Join, and I get an error when the length is > 3356. I get Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error, and the Debug highlights that formula line. Any ideas?

Comment: If you `Debug.Print formula`, then copy it and paste it into a cell manually, does that give you an error?

Comment: Ahh it complains of too many arguments when I do that. I just looked it up and Excel functions have a max limit of 255 arguments (hmm that number seems familiar). So looks like I'm going to have to do a check on how many arguments and error out if it's greater than 255?

Comment: Depends how complicated you want to get with it. Of course you could add a bunch of `Names` in the worksheet, each of which could themselves be defined by 255 separate ranges. But I think generally speaking if you're running in to this problem, it's a good idea to consider overhauling your application. You shouldn't (generally) be dealing with formulae that complex, and if you are, perhaps you need to just do the evaluation in VBA and have it on-demand from a button/etc on the worksheet, rather than a formula.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, David. I appreciate it. The main thing is I need the formula to be paste-able to other sheets and reusable. I’m putting it through absolute worst case scenarios right now, so I doubt I will ever have a formula with 255 arguments. It’s good to know it’s limitations though, so I’ll figure out how to check the number of arguments I’m supplying the formula and error out if it has too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two separate but probably related issues:

- `Range.Address` truncates at a maximum of 255 characters, without error. This is odd, because while Excel is smart enough to not leave you with a partial address string that would raise a 1004, at the same time it's stupid enough to allow an `Address` to truncate, which obviously will yield unexpected results if used in formula, etc.
- There's a kinda-sorta 255 character limit for string arguments to Excel functions if the string is passed `ByVal` (see [this old thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?252750-Parameter-string-cannot-exceed-255-characters)) for discussion, but I've excerpted relevant bits, below) .

> Excel function parameters will accept a **reference** to a string with length of up to 32767 (32k or 2^15 total possible lengths). ... But what if we pass a value instead of a reference?
>
> we can pass a **reference** to a string up to 32k, we can only pass a string **value** up to 255

It seemed like the problem was a result of `Formula` length, but that was a red herring.

You're definitely encountering the truncation issue with `Range.Address`.

## Problem: `Range.Address` truncates at 255 Characters

Because this happens silently, any formula you build based on truncated address is going to be adversely affected; the results won't be what you're expecting because the formula will not represent all parts of the range!

I've logged this as a bug with Microsoft in case you want to follow the issue:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/issues/49

In the meantime, fortunately the solution is remarkably simple (although it was not simple to arrive at!), see if you can adapt to your purposes, but the idea is:

1. Create a `System.Collections.ArrayList` into which we store all of the individual `Area` addresses (alternatively you could use a `Variant` but those are somewhat clunkier what with the `ReDim` etc.)
2. Cast that `ArrayList` to a variant array using the `ToArray()` method
3. Use the result of the `Join` function in your `Formula` string

---

```
Sub example()

Dim myNames As Object
Dim formula as String
Dim k As Long
Dim sumRange As Range
Dim thisArea As Range

' Example:
'   -- creates a range consisting of 100 Areas
'   -- this .Address will truncate to 252 characters!
For k = 1 To 200 Step 2
    Set thisArea = Range("A" & k)
    If sumRange Is Nothing Then Set sumRange = thisArea
    Set sumRange = Union(sumRange, thisArea)
Next

' Iterate the sumRange union and add each Area to an ArrayList
Set myNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each thisArea In sumRange.Areas
    myNames.Add thisArea.Address
Next

' Output to worksheet:
Dim outputCell As Range
Set outputCell = Range("F1")
formula = "=Sum(" & Join(myNames.ToArray(), ",") & ")"
outputCell.Formula = formula

End Sub
```

And you can see the extraordinarily long formula (`Len` == 650) in the worksheet:

[image]

If you're not comfortable working with an `ArrayList`, you could brute force it as a `String:

```
' Iterate the sumRange union and add each Area to our formula string
formula = "=Sum("
For Each thisArea In sumRange.Areas
    formula = formula & thisArea.Address & ","
Next
formula = Left(formula, Len(formula) - 1)
formula = formula & ")"
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for your help. This is so much cleaner than my solution.