VBA Union Result Too Small
This is a lot of words to explain a very simple question:
Why is VBA upset about so few areas in a range variable?
When I try to do the union of two range variables, the result only has some of the second variable appended to the first.
Clearly I'm hitting a size limit, but darned if I can find it.
======================================
I am using Excel 2405 (Build 17628.20188) in Office 365.
Test results are here, and code is attached. Basically "Set Rx3 = Union(Rx1, Rx2)", x =[1,2,3,4]
Union works fine with small test ranges like R11 and R12, with 3 areas each. R13 correctly equals all 6 areas:
Set R11 = ws.Range("$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54")
Set R12 = ws.Range("$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60")
Set R13 = Union(R11, R12)
R13:
$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54,$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60

======================================
But with the ranges I care about (R21 and R22), the result only adds the first one area of R22 ($A$55:$C$55)
onto the end of R21 (w/o error message):
Set R21 = ws.Range("$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23, _
$B$24:$C$24,$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43, _
$B$44:$C$44,$C$45:$C$48,$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54")
Set R22 = ws.Range("$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60,$C$61:$C$64,$B$65:$C$65,$C$66:$C$69,$B$70:$C$70,$C$71:$C$74, _
$B$75:$C$75,$C$76:$C$79,$B$80:$C$80,$C$81:$C$84,$B$85:$C$85,$C$86:$C$89,$B$90:$C$90,$C$91:$C$94, _
$B$95:$C$95,$C$96:$C$99,$B$100:$C$100,$C$101:$C$104")
Set R23 = Union(R21, R22)
R23: 
$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23,$B$24:$C$24, _
$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43,$B$44:$C$44,$C$45:$C$48, _
$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54,$A$55:$C$55

======================================
With R31 = R21 w/o the last area $B$54:$C$54, now R33 has the first two areas from R32 = R22 appended to R31,
$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59:
Set R31 = ws.Range("$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23, _
$B$24:$C$24,$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43,$B$44:$C$44, _
$C$45:$C$48,$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53")
Set R32 = ws.Range("$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60,$C$61:$C$64,$B$65:$C$65,$C$66:$C$69,$B$70:$C$70,$C$71:$C$74, _
$B$75:$C$75,$C$76:$C$79,$B$80:$C$80,$C$81:$C$84,$B$85:$C$85,$C$86:$C$89,$B$90:$C$90,$C$91:$C$94,$B$95:$C$95, _
$C$96:$C$99,$B$100:$C$100,$C$101:$C$104")
Set R33 = Union(R31, R32)
R33: 
$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23,$B$24:$C$24, _
$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43,$B$44:$C$44,$C$45:$C$48, _
$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59

======================================
And lastly, when R41 is the cut-and-paste union of R21 and R22, VBA throws and error:
Set R41 = Range("$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23, _
$B$24:$C$24,$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43,$B$44:$C$44, _
$C$45:$C$48,$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54,$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60,$C$61:$C$64,$B$65:$C$65, _
$C$66:$C$69,$B$70:$C$70,$C$71:$C$74,$B$75:$C$75,$C$76:$C$79,$B$80:$C$80,$C$81:$C$84,$B$85:$C$85,$C$86:$C$89, _
$B$90:$C$90,$C$91:$C$94,$B$95:$C$95,$C$96:$C$99,$B$100:$C$100,$C$101:$C$104")

"Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed
======================================
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
======================================
```
Sub Foo()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
ws.Activate

Dim R11, R12, R13, R21, R22, R23, R31, R32, R33, R41 As Range

Set R11 = ws.Range("$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54")
Set R12 = ws.Range("$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60")
Set R13 = Union(R11, R12)

MsgBox "R11: " & vbNewLine & R11.Address
MsgBox "R12: " & vbNewLine & R12.Address
MsgBox "R13: " & vbNewLine & R13.Address

Set R21 = ws.Range("$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23, _
$B$24:$C$24,$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43, _
$B$44:$C$44,$C$45:$C$48,$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54")
Set R22 = ws.Range("$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60,$C$61:$C$64,$B$65:$C$65,$C$66:$C$69,$B$70:$C$70,$C$71:$C$74, _
$B$75:$C$75,$C$76:$C$79,$B$80:$C$80,$C$81:$C$84,$B$85:$C$85,$C$86:$C$89,$B$90:$C$90,$C$91:$C$94, _
$B$95:$C$95,$C$96:$C$99,$B$100:$C$100,$C$101:$C$104")
Set R23 = Union(R21, R22)

MsgBox "R21: " & vbNewLine & R21.Address
MsgBox "R22: " & vbNewLine & R22.Address
MsgBox "R23: " & vbNewLine & R23.Address

Set R31 = ws.Range("$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23, _
$B$24:$C$24,$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43,$B$44:$C$44, _
$C$45:$C$48,$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53")
Set R32 = ws.Range("$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60,$C$61:$C$64,$B$65:$C$65,$C$66:$C$69,$B$70:$C$70,$C$71:$C$74, _
$B$75:$C$75,$C$76:$C$79,$B$80:$C$80,$C$81:$C$84,$B$85:$C$85,$C$86:$C$89,$B$90:$C$90,$C$91:$C$94,$B$95:$C$95, _
$C$96:$C$99,$B$100:$C$100,$C$101:$C$104")
Set R33 = Union(R31, R32)

MsgBox "R31: " & vbNewLine & R31.Address
MsgBox "R32: " & vbNewLine & R32.Address
MsgBox "R33: " & vbNewLine & R33.Address

Set R41 = ws.Range("$A$4:$C$4,$C$5:$C$8,$B$9:$C$9,$C$10:$C$13,$B$14:$C$14,$C$15:$C$18,$B$19:$C$19,$C$20:$C$23, _
$B$24:$C$24,$C$25:$C$28,$B$29:$C$29,$C$30:$C$33,$B$34:$C$34,$C$35:$C$38,$B$39:$C$39,$C$40:$C$43, _
$B$44:$C$44,$C$45:$C$48,$B$49:$C$49,$C$50:$C$53,$B$54:$C$54,$A$55:$C$55,$C$56:$C$59,$B$60:$C$60, _
$C$61:$C$64,$B$65:$C$65,$C$66:$C$69,$B$70:$C$70,$C$71:$C$74,$B$75:$C$75,$C$76:$C$79,$B$80:$C$80, _
$C$81:$C$84,$B$85:$C$85,$C$86:$C$89,$B$90:$C$90,$C$91:$C$94,$B$95:$C$95,$C$96:$C$99,$B$100:$C$100, _
$C$101:$C$104")

End Sub
```


The range is actually correct, but the address property is limited. For the last part, you can only pass an address string up to 255 characters to Range.

...and you can't break up a long string with underscores like that in VBA...

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956589/range-address-truncated-when-used-in-formula-string-too-long

Excel defines the Ranges correctly when you use Union. Only the address-property has a limit. This is true for defining the range (as you do for R41) but also for reading it.
You can easily check that Excel sets the range correctly by for example count the number of cells. I checked this with your ranges R21..R23
Debug.Print R21.Cells.Count
Debug.Print R22.Cells.Count
Debug.Print R23.Cells.Count

Which resulted in
 63 
 61 
 124 

Note that the total of cells could be smaller than the sum of the cell count of R21 and R22 if they had overlapping cells, but that's not the case here. So obviously R23 contains all cells of R21 and R22 (124 = 63+61).
If you really need the address as String, use a small function like the following. It will concatenate all addresses of all subranges of a range - the subranges can be accessed using the Areas-property of a range.
Function myAddress(r As Range) As String
    Dim a As Long
    For a = 1 To r.Areas.Count
        myAddress = myAddress & IIf(a = 1, "", ",") & r.Areas(a).Address
    Next a
End Function


N.B.
In VBA, if you declare more than one variable with one Dim-statement, you need to provide the data type for every variable separately. Your statement
Dim R11, R12, R13, R21, R22, R23, R31, R32, R33, R41 As Range

will only declare R41 as Range, all the others will be of type Variant. Not a big deal in this case as a Variant can hold anything, including a Range reference. But it can lead to strange errors when a routine expects a Range as parameter and you pass a Variant. So you need to write
Dim R11 As Range, R12 As Range, R13 As Range (...)


Thanks Tim and FunThomas! And good advice on the Dim. The line spacing with _ was just to make stackoverflow happy...I tried .count and it looks good!
